# Append data in for loop in table shape

Tags: export, list-manipulation

I'm trying to append for every element of my for loop a complete table to my file myfile.dat, but everytime I run the loop I get it overwritten by the last cycle.

```
func[y_, m_] := y^2 + m ;
mX = 2;
For[i = 0, i < mX, i++,
 aa1 = Table[{func[y, i], y}, {y, 0.1, 0.2, 0.005}];
 dat1 = Flatten /@ Transpose[{aa1}];
 Export["/Users/federico/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/myfile.dat", 
  dat1, "Table"]]
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Edit.
Here the result from one comment:

```
func[y_, m_] := y^2 + m ;
mX = 2;
t = Table[{y, func[y, i]}, {y, 1, 2, 0.1}, {i, 0, mX - 1}];
dat1 = Flatten /@ Transpose[{t}];
Export["/Users/federico/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica/myfile.dat", \
dat1, "Table"]
```

which gives something close to the solution, but still it prints the y column twice unfortunately

Edit. here the want to be output

[image]

Edit. In this way it works but I've to get rid of those commas and brackets

```
func[y_, m_] := y^2 + m;
mX = 2;
    SetDirectory["/Users/federico/Documents/Wolfram Mathematica"];
    For[i = 0, i < mX, i++,
     For[y = 1, y <= 2, y = y + 0.1, {i, y, func[y, i]} >>> myfile];]
    FilePrint["myfile"]
```

Comment: You could ues a stream with Write. I think you could also use PutAppend.

Comment: Could you use this instead and then flatten as required? `t = Table[{func[y, i], y}, {y, 0.1, 0.2, 0.005}, {i, 0, mX - 1}]`

Comment: @Syed may be working, only problem is it saves the y column twice. Just edited the post with your suggestion

Comment: If you include the desired output, it will be easier to match it. I suggested this as `Table` does the same thing as a `For` loop, but can't say that I understand your problem yet.

Comment: I want to create mX tables where the first column is y and the second one is f(y,i). I'll include the output wait

Comment: `dat1 = (Flatten /@ Transpose[{t}])[[All, {1, 2, 4}]];` Here I am selecting the {1,2,4} columns from the output and `All` the rows. I think this is what you want.

Comment: that's a interesting command! thanks!
Can you see the image I've uploaded?

Comment: I've found a solution making use of two for loops, but now I've to get rid of those brackets and commas

Comment: `func[y_, m_] := y^2 + m;
mX = 2;
t1 = Join @@ 
  Table[{i + 1, y, func[y, i]}, {i, 0, mX - 1}, {y, 1, 2, 0.1}]`

Comment: thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for! If you care to answer I'll confirm your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func[y_, m_] := y^2 + m;
mX = 2;
t1 = Join @@ 
  Table[{i + 1, y, func[y, i]}, {i, 0, mX - 1}, {y, 1, 2, 0.1}]

t1 // TableForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1. & 1. \\
 1 & 1.1 & 1.21 \\
 1 & 1.2 & 1.44 \\
 1 & 1.3 & 1.69 \\
 1 & 1.4 & 1.96 \\
 1 & 1.5 & 2.25 \\
 1 & 1.6 & 2.56 \\
 1 & 1.7 & 2.89 \\
 1 & 1.8 & 3.24 \\
 1 & 1.9 & 3.61 \\
 1 & 2. & 4. \\
 2 & 1. & 2. \\
 2 & 1.1 & 2.21 \\
 2 & 1.2 & 2.44 \\
 2 & 1.3 & 2.69 \\
 2 & 1.4 & 2.96 \\
 2 & 1.5 & 3.25 \\
 2 & 1.6 & 3.56 \\
 2 & 1.7 & 3.89 \\
 2 & 1.8 & 4.24 \\
 2 & 1.9 & 4.61 \\
 2 & 2. & 5. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$